# react-google-maps is refreshing the map when onclick is performed

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I'm trying to use react-google-maps as an latitude and longitude input in my app. In order to get the position that the user selected I'm using the onclick event and it works almost as expected because the marker is set, but the map is refreshing and going to the default center and zoom when the user selects the desired location. How can I avoid this weird behaviour?

```
import React from "react";
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, MarkerWithLabel } from "react-google-maps";

export default class MapTest extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            isMarkerShown: false,
            markerPosition: null
        }
    }
    onMapClick= (e) => this.setState({
        markerPosition: e.latLng,
        isMarkerShown:true}
    );


  render() {
    var Map= withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={12}
      center={ { lat:  4.4360051, lng: -75.2076636 } }
      onClick={this.onMapClick}
      >
    {this.state.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={this.state.markerPosition} />}
        </GoogleMap>));
      return (<Map {...this.props} />);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are creating a new object in each `render` call.

the `withScriptjs(withGoogleMap` should be stored somewhere an re-used

For example

```js
class MapTest extends React.Component {
  //...

  Map = withScriptjs(
    withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={12}
        center={{ lat: 4.4360051, lng: -75.2076636 }}
        onClick={props.onClick}
      >
        {props.children}
      </GoogleMap>
    ))
  );

  render() {
    return <this.Map {...this.props} onClick={this.onMapClick}>
      {this.state.isMarkerShown && (
        <Marker position={this.state.markerPosition} />
      )}
    </this.Map>;
  }
}
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/n05jm6j0jm

Comment: Great answer, but I think you added an old version of your codesandbox. It still calls withScriptjs in the render function.

Comment: @Robb216 indeed. updated the code in the answer and the codesandbox.